# Dynamically changed RequestFilter for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on pretty simple Chrome Extension which handles requests to specified URLs (whitelist) and do some magic.

I have few listeners defined in *js file like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function1, filter,['blocking']);
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function2, filter,['blocking','requestHeaders']);
```

`function1` and `function1` are the regular functions from the same file and they do their job perfectly.

`filter` is the whitelist. It's a variable defined at the top of this file this way:

```
var filter={"urls": ["url_pattern_1", "url_pattern_2"],
               "types": ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "xmlhttprequest"]};
```

Its `urls` block includes even more url patterns than predefined at the `permissions` at `manifest.json`.
And till this time everything works fine.

**The problem** appears when I try to modify `filter` dynamically.
I added input field at extension's settings where user can predifine additional URLs that should be handled by extension (just added to whitelist). I store them at `localStorage` first and adding to `filter['urls']` in additional function. I'm sure they are added by the end of that function, but when I try to send request to any of those URLs extension does nothing, because `filter['urls']` has the same state it was defined at the start, modifications aren't applied.

**So the question is** how I can implement dynamically changed filter that used in the `chrome.webRequest` listeners to get this kind of whitelist logic?

P.S. My main language is Java, this is my first experience with JS and Chrome API, sorry if I miss some "obvious things".

Comment: removeListener first - otherwise adding the same function is ignored regardless of filters.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the response! At this point I'm wondering when does all this `chrome.webRequest...` code executes if it lays at the bottom of my *js file outside any function. Does all that listeners are being registered per every request, or once at the startup?
Second option seems more reasonable to me, it may explain why modified `filter` isn't respected.

Comment: For a persistent background page, only once. For an event page: every time it wakes.